# splitting a git repository

Tags: git

I currently have a git repository that I imported from svn a while ago name school. Inside this school repository I have a folder for each of my classes.

I can't seem how to take this one repository and split it into a repository for each class without losing the entire history of the class, which I would prefer not to do.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git filter-branch` is the way to go. Make a copy of the repo for each subdirectory, then in each copy run a line like this replacing "myclassname" with your actual class name:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter myclassname -- --all
```

A more elaborate description of the process is provided on the [Github help page](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/).

Comment: This worked beautifully thanks. I turned it into a shell script which you can see here: http://github.com/icco/git-explode

Comment: Perhaps also '--remove-empty' to remove commits which do not touch 'myclassname' subdirectory... unless it is turned on by '--subdirectory-filter'.

Comment: The flag is --prune-empty - it isn't turned on with the subdir filter.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command

```
git log -u <path>
```

This will give you a list of changesets (including diff) for each changeset in the specified folder.

From here, you can write a script to parse that output of git log and run each patch on a new repository, keeping the changesets and author info.

Bit of a hack, but it will work.

Comment: There has got to be a better way of doing this than that. I have five years worth of commits...