# Split a GIT repository with messy structure

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

I have done a migration from SVN to GIT, the SVN repository stores some projects in a very messy way. What I have obtained after the migration is a git repository that have the following structure:

```
GIT_REPOSITORY
│
└─FOLDER_A
│   │   
│   └───PROJECT_1
│   │   │   
│   │   └(SOURCE CODE)   
│   │   
│   └───PROJECT_2
│       │   
│       └(SOURCE CODE) 
│
└──FOLDER_B
│   │   
│   └───PROJECT_1
│   │   │   
│   │   └(resources)
│   │
│   └───PROJECT_2
│       │   
│       └(resources)
│
└───FOLDER_C
    |
    └───(Common files of the 3 projects)
```

What I want to do (As it should be from the beginning but I did not do that) are 3 different git repositories each one with the following strucutre:

```
PROJECT_1
│   
└─(Source Code)
│
└─(resources)
│
└─(Common files of the 3 projects)
```

So, the think is that each GIT repository has a combination of its source code, its resources, add the common files.

Is there any straight forward way to do that? (I would like to maintain history of commits)

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [splitting a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552694/splitting-a-git-repository)

Comment: But my split is more complex than that, because it also has to merge three folders

Comment: Perhaps then there are two questions? 1) how to split 2) how to deal with common files across git projects. I think the latter also has been asked (several times) before. Am on mobile now, so searching is not easy. Perhaps you can do a search yourself?